# How to create two line on runtime and calculate it's angle in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, draw, angle

I want to draw an angle by drawing 2 lines and wanted to calculate the angle in my flutter application.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: see [direction](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Offset/direction.html)